# Why is there a difference in the formulas of emission spectrum wavelength in Bohr model and in X-Ray emission?

Tags: atomic-physics

The wavelength of emitted radiation when an electron jumps orbits in the Bohr atomic model is given by

> 1/$\lambda$ = $R_H$ ($\frac{1}{n_f^2}$ - $\frac{1}{n_i^2}$) $Z^2$

But that of X-Ray emission is given by

> 1/$\lambda$ = $1.1 \times 10^7$ ($\frac{1}{n_f^2}$ - $\frac{1}{n_i^2}$) $(Z-1)^2$

Why is there a difference? Why aren't X-Rays treated like any other emissions?

Comment: reference? Where did you find the formulae?

Comment: @SuperCiocia, the first is the Rydberg formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rydberg_formula#Rydberg_formula_for_any_hydrogen-like_element) and the latter is the Moseley's formula (http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/moseley.html#c1) defined in terms of wavelength.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pre-factor is exactly the same thing, look up what $R_H$ is equal to.

The (Z-1) term, is due to the inner electrons shielding part of the nuclear charge such as the electrons involved in the X-ray transitions only see a reduced electric field. It's explained in the link you provided.